# How to solve broken magento 2 installation issue?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I have already changed symlink with copy and write commands on cmd 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento setup:clean

and also remove all files under pub/static except .htaccess

Can anyone suggest me how can I solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: which Magento2 version you have installed?  Look into console there is any js error?

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to verify what Magento 2 release you've downloaded. Have you downloaded the "Full Release with Sample Data" or without the Sample Data. [Magento 2 releases](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) If you've downloaded the release without the sample data, the result you are receiving is expected.

Comment: what should i do to get sampledata and also my admin panel is not working

Comment: Well what you could do is download the release with the sample data. Download it directly from the link which I've showed you. What is wrong with the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Magento2 is it via composer or manually? Please also verify you have installed Magento2 without sample data. If it is the case run the command

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If none of them work check is rewrite mode is enable or not. And Magento2 have .htaccess in root directory and pub/static folder.